# Passing JSON string in Bash flag

Tags: bash

If I want to pass a JSON string into a command in bash, but have that JSON be inside of an argument, how would I do that?

This is what I mean:

```
FOO=$(cat key.json)
my-command.sh --set-string "key=${FOO}"
```

How do I properly include the JSON from `$FOO` in the `"key=${FOO}"` argument?

EDIT: I'm expecting `my-command.sh` to be able to get the value of `key` as a string, but here's the error I keep getting: `wrong type for value; expected string; got []interface {}`

Comment: What's happening instead? A [mcve] would help. Logs of `bash -x yourscript`, even moreso.

Comment: (and, err, how is any of this specific to JSON? It looks like you're just trying to append a string from a file to an argument list; I don't see anything about the request that requires the shell to perform operations that know or care about the format of the content).

Comment: Your code looks fine, what's the problem?

Comment: ...backing up: Your code is 100% fine as-written from a correctness perspective. (Lots of bad practices -- `.sh` extensions [are frowned on](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/), all-caps variable names are [reserved by POSIX-specified convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), `$(cat ...)` forks a subshell and invokes an external process for something the shell could do itself with only builtins -- but nothing that would stop the code from doing what you want).

Comment: It doesn't actually say `all-caps variable names are reserved by POSIX-specified convention`. To quote `Environment variable names used by the utilities ... consist solely of uppercase letters` and `The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications.` Bottom-line, it's safer to use lowercase but it's fine to use uppercase, just be careful.

Comment: I'll update the question, but the command I'm sending this flag to is complaining that the value of `key` is not a string, but rather JSON. Here's the exact error: `wrong type for value; expected string; got []interface {}`